# How to retrieve data from Wikipedia API using JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mediawiki

Here I am fetching the data from Wikipedia using following code. but it is not working for me.

```
var playListURL = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=India&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&callback=?';

$.getJSON(playListURL ,function(data) {
    $.each(data.pages, function(i, item) {
        alert(i);
    });
});
```

DEMO LINK :- http://jsfiddle.net/rushijogle/dyeqy/

Comment: check my answer you will get the proper result by that.

Answer (score 6):

Use the following code to get the data:

```
$.getJSON(playListURL ,function(data) {
        $.each(data.query.pages, function(i, item) {
            alert(item.title);

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Demo is at  http://jsfiddle.net/dyeqy/3/

```
var playListURL = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=India&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&callback=?';

$.getJSON(playListURL ,function(data) {
    var hash = data
    var page_value = ""
    $.each(data["query"]["pages"],function(k,v){
        alert(k)
        $.each(v,function(key,val){
          alert(key)
        });
    });
});
```

Like this you can take the revisions values also.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `data.query.pages` instead of `data.pages`

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dyeqy/2/)**