# How to access the information in this JSON response from Wikipedia API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I think this should be pretty simple, but I've been fighting with it for the last couple of hours and it's becoming a real frustration.

I am making a call to the Wikipedia API with jQuery, as follows:

```
var apiurl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles='+$(this).data('name');

        $.ajax( {
            url: apiurl,
            jsonp: "callback", 
            dataType: 'jsonp', 
            data: '',
            xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

The $(this).data('name') bit is the name of a chemical element, say "Scandium" for discussions sake.

Now, this call works fine, and I get a JSON object back from the API as expected. However I'm struggling to actually handle this information. Below is a screenshot of the object expanded in my javascript console:

[image]

Say I wanted to print out the "extract" part of this object and that alone, how would I do that?

I'd normally just use dot notation and do something along the lines of console.log(data.query.pages...... but then I hit a brick wall, because the next part of the chain is an integer and, not only that, but it's an integer which I won't always know as it will differ depending on what element I'm calling to.

Any advice very much appreciated!

Comment: Similar questions: [How to retrieve data from Wikipedia API using JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735437/how-to-retrieve-data-from-wikipedia-api-using-json) and [Javascript extract data from Wikipedia API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30226255/javascript-extract-data-from-wikipedia-api?lq=1)

Comment: In this case, you'd do `data.query.pages.27116.extract`.

Comment: @oxguy3 [That won't work](http://imgur.com/PVIUOAc).

Comment: Try the links Roberto posted.

Comment: Thanks @Roberto, that was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to dot notation, you can use subscript notation:

```
console.log(data["query"]["pages"][27116]["extract"]);
```

If you don't know what the integer will be ahead of time, you can loop over the attributes of an object like so:

```
var pages = data["query"]["pages"];
for(var key in pages) {
    if(pages.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // Here, 'key' is bound to an attribute
        // name so we can get the associated value like so:
        var value = pages[key];

        // In your example, value should look like
        // {"extract": "Scandium is a chem...", "ns": 0, ... }
    }
}
```

The 'hasOwnProperty' check keeps your loop from considering attributes that 'pages' inherited. This way, the loop will only process data that came back from the API call.