# How to get JSON files from URL

Tags: javascript

I am doing a project with Wikipedia's API and I am seeking for the simplest way to get the data in JSON format. 
The url from when I get the data would be:

```
'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search=' + userInput;
```

I am trying to do it in Vanilla Javascript instead of JQuery.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735437/how-to-retrieve-data-from-wikipedia-api-using-json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve data from Wikipedia API using JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735437/how-to-retrieve-data-from-wikipedia-api-using-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
function getWiki() {
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open("GET", 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?  action=opensearch&format=json&origin=*&search=' + userInput, true);
   xhr.send();
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
       var data = xhr.responseText;
       document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data;
     }
   }
 }
```

More information you can [find here](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/wikipedia-project-ajax-request-with-vanilla-js/75096/9). I hope it helps.

Comment: Working! Thanks a lot. 
Would you recommend me any resource to understand how this work?
Thanks again :)